# Is it possible to create an array with subscripts of variable type through the template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++20

It might be used like this

```
str<int> = "int";
num<double> = 2;
cout << str<int> << endl; // output "int"
cout << num<double> << endl; // output 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, declaring `str` and `num` as follows

```
template <typename>
std::string str;

template <typename>
int num;
```

Are template variables, available starting from C++14.

But take in count that all `str` variables are of type `std::string` and that all `num` variables are of type `int`.

As pointed by Davis Herrings, using specialization (partial or full specialization) you can mitigate this problem. By example, if you want that `str<some-type>`, for a generic type `some-type`, is a integer value except the case `str<int>`, that has to be a `std::string`, you can declare it as follows

```
template <typename>
int str;

template <>
std::string str<int>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
std::string str;

template <typename>
int num;

int main ()
 {
   str<int> = "int";
   num<double> = 2;

   std::cout << str<int> << std::endl; // output "int"
   std::cout << num<double> << std::endl; // output 2
 }
```

Comment: @nullptr I'm actually quite interested in *why* you need this. What problem does it solve?

Comment: @cigien I try to create a universal to_string function that can convert standard library containers to strings, and I need to use different delimiters for different containers, for example, output std::array to [1,2,3], convert std ::vector is output as {1;2;3}.

Comment: @cigien I want a single version of to_string to handle multiple kinds of containers, so I need a container that takes the type as a parameter to store these different separators.

Comment: @nullptr Hmm, ok, that sort of makes sense. I still feel there might be a better approach, but that's fine.

Comment: You can specialize (even partially specialize!) variable templates to have different types in certain cases (unlike function templates which can be overloaded but must match their (explicit) specializations).

Comment: @cigien you are right. i can take type as argument now, but i can't take a standard library container as argument. As a result, i still fail here :(

Comment: @null - standard library container as argument? Do you mean `str<std::vector>` instead of `str<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @DavisHerring - I know... but I suppose you're right: is the case to explicit it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @max66 yeah. but i guess this may not be possible this time.

Comment: @nullptr - maybe not perfect but... instead of a `typename`, the template argument can be a `template <typename...> class`; something as `template <template <typename...> class> std::string str;`. Should be compatible with almost all STL containers (but not `std::array`, unfortunately).